# rescue_from in ApplicationController doesn't catch exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancan, cancancan

I'm setting up a simple RoR application. It mixes ActiveAdmin with CanCan to manage authorizations. When I raise a `CanCan::AccessDenied`, the exception is never rescured as it should:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery
  # Ensure authorization happens on every action in your application
  check_authorization

  # If the user authorization fails, a CanCan::AccessDenied exception will be raised
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def access_denied!(exception)
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new exception.message
  end
end
```

Instead of redirecting to the `root_url`, the Exception is displayed like it is not catched.

[image]

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried taking the bang off `access_denied!` .So just `access_denied` . And you've got all your config in place like `config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied` ?

Comment: at first try `raise CanCan::AccessDenied, exception.message`

Comment: then: `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: -> { ... }`

Comment: well, seems the second advice is not required =)

Comment: @Adamantish  yes, same result without the bang (`access_denied` is called, as defined in active_admin.rb)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ same result too, the exception is not catched

Comment: can you repalce the `CanCan::AccessDenied` wth your own expection class dericed from `StandardError`?

Comment: Still not catched. So I suppose the problem doesn't come from the CanCan's exception.

Comment: Did you double check that no redirect occurs? Maybe you hit another AccessDenied after the redirect?

Comment: @Raffael that's a good idea but I tried to add some debug outputs in the rescue function and they're never displayed neither :/